# How to reuse JWT tokens while writing testing using codeception in laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, jwt, codeception

I am trying to write tests using Codeception in my Laravel 5 application specifically to test the web service. The authentication works using JWT tokens. I have successfully written and run a test that verifies a token being returned on authentication.

```
<?php
$I = new ApiTester($scenario);
$I->wantTo('authenticate a user');
$I->haveHttpHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
$I->sendPOST('authenticate', [
    'username' => 'carparts',
    'email' => 'admin@admin.com',
    'password' => 'password'
]);
$I->seeResponseCodeIs(200);
$I->seeResponseIsJson();
```

Works like a charm. The problem I am facing is how to use the token returned here in other requests because obviously all other request will require a token to proceed so do I authenticate and fetch a new token before testing every API call or is there a way around this?

I can already do this:

```
<?php 
$I = new ApiTester($scenario);
$I->wantTo('see a list of all users');
$I->haveHttpHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImNhcnBhcnRzIiwic3ViIjoiMSIsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6XC9cL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo4MDAwXC9hcGlcL2F1dGhlbnRpY2F0ZSIsImlhdCI6IjE0NDY2NDA0ODYiLCJleHAiOiIxNDQ2NjQ0MDg2IiwibmJmIjoiMTQ0NjY0MDQ4NiIsImp0aSI6ImZmYTNkZjc4Yzg5YjdmNDNhYThkZTRmZTViZWI4YjI3In0.9UBZgEz3hHTEMlK5hPzYRV1DsAI3TSSHSZxV0FcBLio');
$I->sendGET('/users');
$I->seeResponseCodeIs(200);
$I->seeResponseIsJson();
```

But this is not very efficient for the obvious reasons that I am hard coding the token. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can grab the token from json by using call to `$I->grabDataFromJsonResponse()`. Example assumes your responses is something like:

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "token": "xxxxxxxx"
}
```

Then your test would be something like below. Warning, untested code.

```
$I = new ApiTester($scenario);
$I->wantTo('authenticate a user');
$I->haveHttpHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
$I->sendPOST('authenticate', [
    'username' => 'carparts',
    'email' => 'admin@admin.com',
    'password' => 'password'
]);
$I->seeResponseCodeIs(200);
$I->seeResponseIsJson();

$token = $I->grabDataFromJsonResponse('token');

$I->deleteHeader('Authorization'); /* Needed with old version of codeception. */
$I->amBearerAuthenticated($token);

$I->sendGET('/users');
$I->seeResponseCodeIs(200);
$I->seeResponseIsJson();
```

Comment: But I have to re use the token in other test files. Which is why I was confused. But I used a similar approach and I basically save the token in a file after the authentication test so that is used by other tests but this is helpful too. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3):

you can define your general methods in ApiTester class which is located in _support directory, then you can reach it in all test classes

this is what i do

```
class ApiTester extends \Codeception\Actor
{
   use _generated\ApiTesterActions;

   private $userToken = null;

   public function getUserToken()
   {
      if ($this->userToken) {
         return $this->userToken;
      }
      $this->generateUserToken();
      return $this->userToken;
   }

private function generateUserToken()
{

    $email = 'testUser@test.com';
    $password = '123456789';
    $I = $this;
    $encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder(12);
    $I->haveInDatabase('users', [
        'email' => $email,
        'status' => UserConstants::USER_STATUS_VERIFIED,
        'password' => $encoder->encodePassword($password, 'dasdsa'), // salt is not important for Bcrypt
        'created_at' => '2019-01-01 20:20:20',
        'updated_at' => '2019-01-01 20:20:20',
    ]);

    $userId = $I->grabFromDatabase('users', 'id', [
        'email' => $email
    ]);

    $I->haveHttpHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    $I->sendPOST('/api/v1/auth/login', ['username' => $email, 'password' => $password]);
    $response = $I->grabResponse();
    $responseArray = json_decode($response, true);
    $this->userToken = $responseArray['token'];

 }

}
```

and in my test classes I use it like this

```
class UserControllerCest
{

  /**
   * @param ApiTester $I
  */
  public function testIndexAction(ApiTester $I)
  {
    $token = $I->getUserToken();

    //we should login first
    $I->haveHttpHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    $I->amBearerAuthenticated($token);
    $I->sendGET('/api/v1/posts');
    $I->seeResponseCodeIs(\Codeception\Util\HttpCode::OK); // 200
  }
}
```